# Pandas read_csv multiple IPs from CSV row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to Python and I want to perform some Reverse DNS lookups on IPs in a csv file. The CSV has an 'ip' column with addresses in the following format:

[example of source input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cmUG.png)

My python script is working for the single IPs, but I am unsure how I can read the rows with multiple IP addresses.

```
#pip install pandas
#pip install dnspython
#pip install xlrd, pip install xlsxwriter

### Import needed libraries ###
import pandas as pd
import time 

from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
from dns import resolver,reversename

### Time variable ###
startTime = time.time()


#Custom Delimiter
custom_delimiter = ','
logs = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\rdnslookup\\input_file\\logs.csv', sep=custom_delimiter, quotechar=',', engine='python', converters={'ip': lambda x:x.strip('["]')}, on_bad_lines = "skip") 

#Diagnostic print statement
print(logs.head)

# Create new Dataframe that removed duplicate IP addresses
logs_filtered = logs.drop_duplicates(['ip']).copy() 

### Perform DNS lookup on deduplicated IPs ###
def reverseDns(ip):
  try: 
    return str(resolver.query(reversename.from_address(ip), 'PTR')[0])
  except: 
    return 'N/A'

### Create DNS column with the reverse IP DNS result ###
logs_filtered['dns'] = logs_filtered['ip'].apply(reverseDns)

### Merge DNS column to full logs matching IP ###
logs_filtered = logs.merge(logs_filtered[['ip','dns']], how='left', on=['ip'])

### Output IP addresses to CSV with DNS lookups ###
writer = ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\rdnslookup\\output_file\\validated_logs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',)
logs_filtered.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.close()
```

I tried changing the quotechar to ' " ', but that did not remove the quotes from the lines with multiple addresses, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get one IP per row?

Comment: Why would you use pandas for this?  Just use the `csv` module and do the split yourself.

Comment: Have a look at "Explode". https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: Can you provide the actual raw CSV? (not a table)

Comment: @not_speshal - Exactly, I am looking to have one IP per row on the output csv

Comment: That looks like a JSON encoded field.  Think you need to first parse the CSV format off to give columns, then parse that column as JSON format to give you the IP address as a list of strings

Comment: `logs = pd.read_csv("logs.csv").explode("ip")`?

Comment: @not_speshal Might want a `apply(json.loads)` before that call to `explode`, op needs to include their data as it's very ill defined so far

Comment: @SamMason it seems StackOverflow wont allow me to attach the .csv input file here, but the format is as shown in the table above. I updated the code block with the entire script if that helps define what I am doing better.

Comment: You do understand that's NOT a CSV file, right?  That's a multi-record JSON file.

Comment: @Sulphuric-16 just copy and paste some lines, e.g. header and a couple of rows.  That's the nice thing about textual file formats!

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from "when all you have is a hammer, the whole world starts to look like a nail" syndrome.  Pandas is nifty, but when you're wasting time trying to squish your problem into a form that fits pandas, it's not productive.  Your problem is more easily solved by reading it for what it is -- a list of JSON records.

I don't have the `dns` module installed, so I faked it.

```
import pandas as pd
import time 
import json

#from dns import resolver,reversename

### Time variable ###
startTime = time.time()

rows = []
for row in open('logs.csv'):
    if row[0] != '[':
        continue
    data = json.loads(row)
    rows.extend(data)

# Remove duplicates.

rows = list(set(rows))

### Perform DNS lookup on deduplicated IPs ###

def reverseDns(ip):
  try: 
    return ip[::-1]
#    return str(resolver.query(reversename.from_address(ip), 'PTR')[0])
  except: 
    return 'N/A'

dns = [reverseDns(row) for row in rows]

logs = pd.DataFrame( {'ip': rows, 'dns': dns})
print(logs)
```

Output:

```
            ip          dns
0  192.168.1.3  3.1.861.291
1  192.168.1.1  1.1.861.291
2  192.168.1.2  2.1.861.291
```